# I'm working with File Manager in Swift in Replit. I'm getting a file doesn't exist error for both createDirectory and createFile operations

Tags: swift, replit

How to both create and access these files in Replit? With `FileManager` reference, I've followed the proper syntax for `createDirectory` as well as `createFile` but I'm unable to create and access the files.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using? What are the errors that you get? I'm not familiar with Replit's latest feature set — does it even give you access to a file system to create and store files on?

Comment: The question cannot be answered as it is. We don't have the proper understanding of what you wrote.

BUT, imagining that you actually did use the correct syntax, it can be a problem of access privileges. In that case it would be related to your Account and your Operative System, not the program.

Are you granted the privilege to write in that folder (or directory)? Are you granted the privilege to create a new folder? In example, Windows 10 doesn't allow programs to write in their Programs folder.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour] and read [ask] for tips how to write a good question. You can [edit] your question with a [example] showing what you have already tried and what part is not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.